# Removing DOM element from loaded Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to remove all img tags from the DOM and the elements that follow each one. The catch is that my content is all loaded via jQuery ajax and so by executing a $('img').remove(); the content hasn't loaded and so there are no imgs to remove. Any suggestions?

```
$.ajax({
    url: entry.link,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
        $('#entriesHtml').append("<h3><a href='#'>" + entry.title + "</a></h3>" + "<div>" + $(response).find(".ui-widget-detail").html() + "</div>");       
    }
});
```

Comment: You can do that in the success callback instead of doing the same outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render the html with `display:none`, remove the img tags, and then `show()` the html.